# PHP generates invalid JSON

Tags: jquery, json, datatables

I have the following JSON string that I'm passing from a PHP file via an echo when called from an HTML file via a jQuery AJAX call.

The string contains HTML which is fed into a DataTables cell.  The returned JSON appears to be interpreting `</` as a line feed as it's inserting ASCII 10 and 13 (per a text to ASCII conversion website), which is causing DataTables to see this as invalid JSON.

I'm unclear as to what is generating the misplaced ASCII.

HTML (DataTables load):

```
var mydatatable = $("#myassets").DataTable(
{
    "ajax": "../php/fetchmydata.php",
    "type": "POST",
    "dataType": "json",
    "columns": [
        {"data":"teamName","width":"30%"},
        {"data":"teamImg","width":"20%"},           
        {"data":"cluesFoundCount","width":"5%"},
        {"data":"assets","width":"30%"},
        {"data":"scores","width":"5%"}
    ]
});//end dataTable
```

PHP (fetchmydata.php):

```
$myjson = '{"teamName":"<div class=\'teamblock\'><span class=\'bold\'>' . $row['TeamName'] . '</span><div>rick</div></div>"';
$myjson.='}';
echo '{"data":[' . $myjson . ']}';

return $myjson;
```

Comment: Build an array in PHP and use [`json_encode`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php) instead. It's safer and easier to read.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use [json_encode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php) to avoid errors.

Use the following code instead:

```
$data = array(
   "data" => array(
      array(
         "teamName" =>
            '<div class="teamblock"><span class="bold">' . 
            $row['TeamName'] . 
            '</span><div>rick</div></div>',
         "teamImg" => "",
         "cluesFoundCount" => "",
         "assets" => "",
         "scores" => ""
      )
   )
);

echo json_encode($data);
```

However to avoid passing a lot of data via Ajax, it's recommended to produce HTML on the client-side using [columns.render](http://datatables.net/reference/option/columns.render) option.

Answer (score -1):

The `<div>` tag generates an ASCII 10 and 13.  I changed the `div` to `span` and the JSON properly renders.